# Does anyone have experience with gcc's LTO (C++)?

Tags: c++, gcc

My main interest is with moving code from header files to source files (for decoupling), but keeping the same performance for the inlined stuff.

I'm not sure where to get started, could someone explain what to do?

Comment: Perhaps you could expamd on what you mean by LTO?

Comment: Link-time optimization?

Answer (score 5):

I did some testing on Firefox and LTO showing memory use, compile times and runtimes
[At my blog](http://hubicka.blogspot.ca/2014/04/linktime-optimization-in-gcc-2-firefox.html) also comparing with LLVM. LTO is quickly developing, GCC 4.9 fares considerably better than previous releases.  It is not always obvious how to get it working right for a given application, the text describes the main problems you can encounter (lack of linker plugin, using fat LTO files and throwing away the LTO part at link and others)

Answer (score 4):

We have made very limited experiments. In our case, performance gains where quite neglictible, but as we had already taken care of having good inlining, that's not extremely surprising.

However, enabling LTO incurred a huge increase in GCC's memory consumption, basically making parallel compilation impossible on our 4 CPU / 4 GB developpement machines, so we suspending the experiment and are waiting for future versions to try again.

Comment: that's sad; LTO makes C far more usable, imo; currently, it's often impossible to use opaque pointers because you need the full definitions for inline functions

Comment: Did you try `-fwhopr` option for lowering memory consumption?

Comment: Is there any update on this? Have you tried it again yet? The GCC 4.7.0 changelog indicates that significant improvements have been made (the example they give is building firefox using LTO, with GCC 4.7 requiring 3GB to do that, where previous versions required 8GB)

Comment: You might get better results with WHOPR. -fwhopr: This is similar to -flto but it splits compilation to achieve scalability. → http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization